# Yii2 - Update user identity info

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have implemented a login screen. I understand how identity works. I can read user info from identity like this:

```
Yii::$app->user->identity->firstname
```

Has Yii a way to update identity info, in case user update his/her name on profile?

I have been checking the code, and I see Yii triggers an event to set the web/user identity:

```
$event = new UserEvent([
            'identity' => $identity,
        ]);
        $this->trigger(self::EVENT_BEFORE_LOGOUT, $event);
```

So since Identity is an instance of User maybe I could do:

```
$event = new UserEvent([
                'identity' => $identity,
            ]);
            $this->trigger('afterSave', $event);
```

Any security issues could bring this? any other ways to do it?

**UPDATE**
I have found a method called "setIdentity":

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html#setIdentity%28%29-detail

I will try it and see if it is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end the answer was easier than I thought. It updates automatically!!! when you update the user. In any case it was useful to learn something new. In Yii 1 worked different that was the cause of my confusion. Thanks for the help.